# Is there a closed form solution to tan(x)=ax?

Tags: closed-form

If I have

*tan(x) = ax (a >= 1)*

I'd like to solve for x(a), though essentially only the first positive solution.

Comment: No, there is no closed form solution. It is quite easy to find it numerically though.

Comment: I believe, you can introduce own "user" function for this.